# Powershell search / prompt specific hotfix

Tags: powershell

I am after a script that will prompt or you can enter in a commandline the KB article you need to find on a computer. So far I have the following below, it will prompt you for the KB and you enter it and it comes back yes or no if it has found it. 
For a test I typed in KB123456 and made up other Kb's and it said it found it, bit stranage. Am I missing something?

```
Clear-Host
$strComputer = $env:computername #Sets the local computer name
$Id = Read-host 'What is the Hotfix ID?' #Prompts for KB article

$Hotfix = Get-HotFix -Id $Id -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue


   if ($hotfix)
   {       
       write-host $strComputer "does not have $ID installed."
   } 
   Else {
      Write-Host $strComputer "has $id installed!"
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
  if ($hotfix)
   {       
      Write-Host $strComputer "has $id installed!"
   } 
   Else {
       write-host $strComputer "does not have $ID installed."
    }
```

Comment: No does not work, just put in a KB number that is on my Win8 box and it said 'does not have KB2850074 installed.' Saying that even typing in get-hotfix on the box says it is not install..strange

Comment: ok I was doing it against MS Office 2013 KB's..just tried it against Windows KB's and it works...strange.